# Add next pressed button value to input javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

this is my first question here.

I'm a newbie on programming and i'm trying to code a simple calculator in javascript.

Here's my problem: i can add the value of the button to my calculator display, but can't add the next button value to it.

Here's my code:

```
function addToDisplay(x) {
  $('#display').val(x);
  $('#display').add(x);
        if (x === 'c') {
    $('#display').val('');
  }
};
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? The question is not really clear for me, especially the usage of `add()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the existing value of the display **plus** the new one via string concatenation:

```
function addToDisplay(x) {
  $('#display').val($('#display').val() + x);

  if (x === 'c') {
    $('#display').val('');
  }
};
```